SQL queries are slow in latest versions
We have updated our SQL server to latest 2022 version for expecting better performance but it turns to be opposite for even simple queries. Such as the below query which runs in compatibility level 100 with just 250 logical reads and executes in 10 milliseconds. If we change the compatibility level to 160 , its reads increased to 12000 and duration to 270 ms.
SELECT TOP 1 id, detail 
FROM shopdetail WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE id> 589530 AND detail <>''  
ORDER BY id ASC

When we checked the execution plan the its was changed to index scan from index seek.


Can some one help how to make optimizer to use the efficient plans other than using the option hints ?
ID column is the primary key and detail column has the non clustered index.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[shopdetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [pk_shopdetailID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


Compatibility 100 is SQL Server 2008, which ran on the old cardinality estimator (the new one came in SQL Server 2014). The fact your query is doing a scan, however, means there's no indexes to help the data engine find the row(s) you've asked for. Do you have any indexes on the table, other than the clustered index? What is the definition of your clustered index as well?

Why, also, are you using NOLOCK? You do understand what that does, right?

"ID column is the primary key and detail column has the non clustered index." What does this mean? That you have an index defined as CREATE INDEX <Indexname> ON dbo.shopdetail (detail);? That's unlikely to be helpful here, in truth, as the index would need to be scanned until it finds an id greater than 589530 after is seeks to row with a value great than '' for detail. The most relevant index would be defined on id and detail, but you (presumably) would want to INCLUDE some other columns.

@ThomA , Have updated the question with index details. and NOLOCK we are aware the pitfalls. Thank you

"NOLOCK we are aware the pitfalls" Then you know you really shouldn't be using it. :)

change the compatibility level to 160 did you refresh the statistics though? Also, did you notice that big, expensive Top N Sort operation in the fast execution plan? detail <>'' isn't selective and may allow millions of matches. Without updated statistics the server won't how many such values there are. Or there are so many it decides there's no point trying to use the index that covers details. Which, by the way, isn't included in the question

@ThomA, Thank you for your inputs, actually the id got passed from application is not exist in that table. Is that could be the reason for a index scan in 160 level and not in 100 level?

@PanagiotisKanavos, Yes we rebuild the indexes and updated statistics before execute in the 160 compatibility level.

What is the result of SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(CASE WHEN id> 589530 THEN 1 END), COUNT(NULLIF(detail, '')) FROM shopdetail the result of that would tell us which index is best to use.

@Charlieface
(No column name) (No column name) (No column name)
926993 926993 0

There are no rows with a value for detail other than '', and all IDs have a have greater than 589530? So why the filter? This is starting to smell like a XY Problem.

Similar question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286031/ms-sql-server-2019-is-slower-than-sql-server-2008

@ThomA, Appreciate if you can help me to understand my concern about performance degradation after moving to 160 level, rather than question the application logic. They do exist for purpose. Thank you for your understanding.

The problem is you have a query where you want to scan the entire table for a row that doesn't exist. Why do you want to do that?

@ThomA, True that not exist at the moment,  but can come anytime and the ids are passed from the application and we don't have the control over it.

This looks like ROWGOAL stuff (top 1), there have been similar questions before about it, but not sure about the solution. Does this page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4051361-optimizer-row-goal-information-in-query-execution-plan-added-in-sql-server-2014-2016-and-2017-ec130d21-1adc-3d3d-95a5-cdb075722269 help anything? How many rows do you have in shopdetail ? And do the actual query have parameters or hardcoded literal values?

I suggest you create a filtered index. This means that it can just scan this one index, which should be very small or no rows at all.
CREATE INDEX IX_Detail_Filtered ON shopdetail
(id) INCLUDE (detail) WHERE (detail <> '');


That index changed the index scan to index seek and fixed my problem. Thank you very much
